# Xcode7 Swift - iPad App NavigationItem title not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I am using the latest XCode 7 Beta and creating a simple iPad application using Swift programming language.

This is how I have setup my Storyboard:

1. I started with a single view app template
2. Then I embedded the view in a NavigationController
3. I then created my "Login" view UI elements
4. I then dropped a TabBarViewController onto the storyboard
5. I then linked the "Login" button to the TabBarController
6. Then within each view of the tabbar, I added a NavigationBarItem and set a title

When the app runs and I click the login button, I am taken to the TabBarController, but I do not see the title.

This is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

The app runs like this (after I clicked the login button):

[image]

Any ideas why? Am I using the controls incorrectly? Or is this a bug in Xcode 7 Beta?

Here's my test project zipped: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=90125200274831974206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue exists even in older Xcode versions. I resolved this issue in next steps:

1. Create custom class for `Sales` and `Customers`
2. [image]
3. Add `self.tabBarController!.title = "Sales or Customers"` in `viewWillAppear()` method for each custom class.

Comment: This method works. I didn't even had to use a navigation item. Any idea why I have to do this via code? why doesn't it work using `NavigationItem` via the Storyboard?

Comment: When I click the login button from the `Login` view, I am taken to the "TabBarController", so the back button says `< Login` (as per my screenshot). Any idea how to change this to say `< Logout` instead?

Comment: I think I have made it work partially. When I use this code: `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Logout";` the back button now says `Logout`. However, when I go back to the login screen, it still says `Logout`, should it not not `Login`?

Comment: Figured it out. I had to do the same on the login view controller in the `viewWillAppear` like this: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Login";`

Comment: @Latheesan 1. I have no idea why this works only from code. I had the same problem maybe 1.5 year ago. I've solved it in this way. 2. You can add `self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)` in `viewDidLoad` SalesViewController class. But notice that I've not specified `target` and `action`. You need to do this manually from code.

Answer (score 0):

Please set title in view didload:

```
navigationItem.title = "title"
```

Comment: Does not work. I created a new view controller class called `SalesViewController` and linked it to the view and when I ran it, I still don't see the title. This is my code: http://pastebin.com/ZdHpChbC (http://i.imgur.com/D3Thc8k.png)

Comment: dont use navigationcontroller there should be navigationitem

Comment: Sorry it autocorrected to navigationcontroller. I tried `navigationitem` and it sitll doesn't work.

Comment: first check: if self.tabbarcontroller != nil than use self.tabbarcontroller.navigationItem.title = "title"