# Xcode 7 & Swift - Static UITableView with TextField not editable

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a simple setting view for my application (being coded in Xcode7 in Swift). So, I created a `Table View Controller` and set the `Table View Contents` to `Static Cells`. I created the sections and rows and dropped a `TextField` into each cell (without border) and configured it so it looks like this in storyboard:

[image]

This is my scene breakdown:

[image]

When I run the app in simulator, it looks like this:

[image]

- TextField placeholder text aren't showing
- TextField is not editable

Any ideas why?

Comment: Just a long shot here but have you set constraints/auto layout? Perhaps the frame size is different at runtime which doesn't allow you to see the textfield.

Comment: I have set constraints on each of the `TextField` (as shown on scene breakdown screenshot - I used `Add missing constraints`). P.s. I even tried removing the constraints, it still did not work.

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Have you tried running it on an iPhone Simulator or just the iPad? You could try to replace one of them with a TextFields with a label and see if the issue still persists? Otherwise, you could create a class for each cell and assign them, but that is long winded and shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I've removed the textfield and replaced it with a Label, that still does not show. I am afraid I am working on an ipad app, so it does not matter even if it works on iPhone simulator.

Comment: Right, I'm almost certain this is a constraints issue. Try set the constraints manually or reset to suggested constraints first

Comment: I agree with air6199, and since the workspace is so simple, maybe just start with a fresh workspace and don't add constraints from the beginning.

Comment: I have deleted the entire TableviewController and started from scratch and it still does not work. If I start a blank new XCode project, it appears to work. However I do not want to do this, I have spent considerable amount of time in my current Xcode project, I do not want to bin it and start over again. This looks like a glitch, can't be too sure though.

Comment: Sorry for your troubles Latheesan, that sucks, can you post more of your storyboard so we can try to help further?  Or did you figure it out?

Comment: My story board layout is something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543873/xcode7-swift-ipad-app-navigationitem-title-not-showing (I had another issue with my project, so i made a test project)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
    YourTextField.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

and set the placeholder text programmatically?

If you have it inside a cell which I assume use:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(indexPath.row, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.YourTextField.placeholder = "Your placeholder text"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It's already ticked on the Xcode editor for each text field. Why must I set it programatically ?

Comment: Just to ensure. Sometimes it helps to set it programmatically again.

Comment: Could you post your related class?

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

Your constraints might be moving the text views outside of the visible portion of the cell.

I would try removing your constraints and rerunning the program.

Here's a view of my workspace that runs just fine:
[image]

Here's a link to the github project https://github.com/Rnorback/statictablewithfields

Cheers!

Comment: I have deleted the whole Table view Controller and started from scratch again and this time, I did not set any constraints. It still does not work.

Comment: By the way, this table view controller is embedded within a navigation controller. Not sure if that affects anything.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a starter project that should work for you.  Let me know if you still have issues.  Cheers!  And yes, my project is embedded in a nav controller.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can confirm your sample project works. I also created my own blank new Xcode project to test the theory and it also works. It appears its not working with my existing project, even if I recreate the TableViewController from scratch. Any ideas why? I cannot dump this project and start over. What's causing this?

Comment: You can try and copy and paste the view controller from my project into your project.  That might work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the cells were not editable until I overrode the tableview commit editing delegate function.

```
func tableView(
     _ tableView: UITableView,
     commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
     forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     }
```

Kind of counterintuitive considering it returns nothing.